# Very confused on how Grunt and node work together

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, stylus

I am trying to add the `bootstrap-styl` package to a nodejs project. I have a Gruntfile with some simple tasks, all of which work fine. However when I add `@import` to my `style.styl` file (which compiles the stylus) I get an error for bootstrap not found.

This is where I get very confused regarding what is in charge of what and where I need to be focusing my attention. I have tried a few things but nothing seems to be working (though the site will generally open, I only get errors when changing my Gruntfile of styl sheet).

This is my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    stylus: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          compress: false
        },
        files: {
          'public/stylesheets/style.css': ['public/stylesheets/style.styl']
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      // Watch stylus files in "styl" directory
      stylus: {
        files: ['public/stylesheets/*.styl'],
        tasks: ['stylus']
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "watch" & "stylus" tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

I have the bootstrap-styl package installed, but I don't understand how to fit it in. The npm page only give the compile function for adding into `app.js`. This is the error from running `grunt watch` and changing the file:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "public/stylesheets/style.styl" changed.
Running "stylus:compile" (stylus) task
>> Error: public/stylesheets/style.styl:3:9
>>    1| 
>>    2| @import 'nib'
>>    3| @import 'boostrap'
>> --------------^
>>    4| 
>>    5| @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand')
>>    6| 
>> 
>> failed to locate @import file boostrap.styl
Warning: Stylus failed to compile. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

It looks like having `bootstrap-styl` at all does nothing, I can't `@import`, I'm really not sure how this is supposed to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is "bootstrap.styl" inside your stylesheets folder? The error says "failed to locate @import file boostrap.styl"

Comment: The thing is that bootstrap-styl should take care of this. I am 99% sure I shouldn't be creating that file.

Comment: the import nib right above it doesn't require any such file, it gets used automatically, bootstrap doesn't work though

Comment: Ok, the other thing I noticed is that they don't include the single quotes around bootstrap in their documentation, i.e. "@import boostrap", instead of "@import 'bootstrap'"